# How to figure out if a function is Big O, Big Ω, or Big θ of x?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm working on my last Discrete Mathematics online question set at the moment, and I've finished everything except this one problem on Big O. Essentially, it gives me 5 functions, and I have to figure out if each one is O(x), Ω(x), or θ(x).

While I (at least vaguely) understand what each term means, I've not been able to get it correct, and I've only been allotted 3 attempts, so I wanted to get a solid answer before I press submit for the last time.

My understanding, graphically, is that if f(x) is always less than x after a certain point, then f(x) is O(x). If it's always more, than that would be Ω(x). If it's both above and below the function after the given point, though, then it's θ(x).

Here are the five functions I must check: f(x) = 10, g(x) = 3x + 7, h(x) = x^2 + x + 1, j(x) = 5log(x), and k(x) = floor(x).

As for my current answers, f(x) is both above and below x, so I said f(x) was θ(x). g(x) is both above and below, but since the question didn't specify I imagined it meant after x = 0, so I said g(x) was O(x). This is the same case for h(x). j(x) is always less than x, so I said j(x) was Ω(x), and k(x) was always less than or equal to as well, so I said it was Ω(x).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Based on your current answers, I think you have a *very* serious misunderstanding of what the symbols mean. Having a function be $O(x)$ means that $f(x) \le Cx$ for all large $x$, and $\Omega(x)$ means that $f(x) \ge Cx$ for all large $x$, and $\Theta(x)$ means both conditions at the same time. So a constant is *not* $\Theta(x)$, but a linear function like $3x + 7$ is. So actually it turns out that, unfortunately, all five of your answers are wrong.

Comment: Also, it's not just about the graph of a function being above the graph of $x$ or below the graph of $x$. The graph of $2x$ lies well above the graph of $x$, but $2x = \Theta(x)$, as is $1/2 x$.

Comment: Okay, so bear with me here, but when you say it must be less than/greater than for all large x, you mean for all larger x's, correct? So in this case, for a function to be O(x) or Ω(x), it has to remain smaller or larger than x times some constant, respectively, regardless of the constant you multiply by? Whereas for a function to be Θ(x), it has to be greater than x with one constant, and less than with another?

Comment: So I gave it a shot earlier and got 80%, but I still have one more chance to resubmit. I had f(x) and g(x) as Θ(x), h(x) as Ω(x), j(x) as O(x), and k(x) as Θ(x). I only have one wrong, and from what you said I'd imagine it's f(x) since you said it can't be Θ(x). If you don't mind, could you please explain why that's wrong (or if I'm misinterpreting it, could you explain whatever my error is)? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:**  A thorough introduction about the asymptotic notation Big $O$, Big $\Omega$ and friends is  presented in chapter 9 *Asymptotics*  in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

Going through sections 9.2 and (parts of) 9.3 might improve your understanding of the concepts to answer questions of this kind in a much more comfortable manner.